# nginx ingress rewrite-target problem when in dynamic url "/' comes in

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress

Below is the kubernetes manifest for ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-services
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 200m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "24576k"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-body-buffer-size: 200M
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /test(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test-service
            port:
            number: 8080
```

There is an url in application https://example.com/test/v1/data/scopes/C0/entity-data. After C0 in url data is dynamic and when a dynamic data which already includes / comes up eg https://example.com/test/v1/data/scopes/C0/equity/ordinary%20sshares comes then url doesn't work as after C0 it already has "equity/ordinary%20sshares" which is generated dynamically. Can you please help me how to rewrite "equity/ordinary%20sshares" so that it accepts it as value of C0.
Also C0/value is last part of url.

Comment: Can you check the provided [article](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/) and [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#examples) if it can be useful to you.